# Is there anyway to style or change color of background of keyboard toolbar in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I am presenting a toolbar on top of my keyboard to dismiss the keyboard using the following modifier:

```
.toolbar {
        ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {
            Spacer()
            Button {
                UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "keyboard.chevron.compact.down.fill")
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there anyway to change the color of the toolbar background and maybe give it upper right and upper left corner radius?  So far I can only change the color of the symbol or text that I add to the toolbar but not the toolbar background itself.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this repo [Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/swiftui-introspect) to find the superview of your `KeyboardToolBar` and then change the color of the background. For example:

```swift
.toolbar {
     ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {
           KeyboardToolBar()
              .introspect(.view, on: .iOS(.v17)) { view in
                    view.superview?
                        .superview?
                        .superview?
                        .superview?.backgroundColor = .green
          }
     }
}
```

Maybe it seems a little bit weird, but it can just solve your issue. :)

Here is the screenshot of the effect:

[image: here is the screenshot of the effect]

A bit of refinement below makes your code looks better:

```swift
@ViewBuilder
func keyboardToolbarBackgroundColor(_ color: Color) -> some View {
    self
        .introspect(.view, on: .iOS(.v17)) { view in
            view.superview?.superview?.superview?.superview?.backgroundColor = UIColor(color)
        }
}
```

In your ContentView:

```swift
.toolbar {
    ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {
          KeyboardToolBar()
               .keyboardToolbarBackgroundColor(.green)
    }
}
```